# Jquery draggable doesn't reach edges of container

Tags: jquery, css, draggable, jsfiddle

I'm very happy with my code at this [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/robinandrews73/kfm98d80/), but for some reason I can't fathom, the triangles won't reach the top or right edges of their container. I'd be very grateful if someone could take a look and explain why.

```
#sandpit{
    /* display: inline-block; */
    position: relative;
    margin:20px auto;
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 4px solid #7b6eb1;
    border-radius: 5px;
    /* background-color: #FFC469; */
    background-color: #FFFCCF;
    padding: 2px;
}

.draggable{
    margin: 0;
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your css for newTriangle to:

```
.newTriangle{
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain why this works, and why the original version didn't please?